# How to check the type of a view widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview, android-layout

How to get that working:

```
 if(findViewById(ResIdWithUnkownType) instanceof Bitmap)
 {
       Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) findViewById(ResIdWithUnkownType);
 } else if(findViewById(ResIdWithUnkownType) instanceof ImageView)
 {
       ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(ResIdWithUnkownType);
 }
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you'd be better off saving the `View` object before checking it's type rather than calling `findViewById` over and over again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second block would work just fine. The problem is the first one: `findViewById` returns a `View` object **always**, and `Bitmap` is not a `View`, so the first `if` statement will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Actually, it's related to this, if u want to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864977/android-how-to-exchange-an-image-in-a-layer-list-by-a-bitmap

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer but For Others who check this Question,in some cases `instanceof` does not work(I do not know why!),for example if your want to check if view type is `ImageView` or `ImageButton`(i tested this situation) , it get them the same, so you scan use this way :

```
//v is your View
    if (v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.ImageView")) {
        Log.e("imgview", v.toString());
        imgview = (ImageView) v;
    } else if (v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.ImageButton")) {
        Log.e("imgbtn", v.toString());
        imgbtn = (ImageButton) v; 
    }
```